# Net Core API Dependency injection without having repository library to be referenced in API project

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to do WEB API project in .NET Core 3.1 with dependancy injection and in `Startup` class, of my web api project I added this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddControllers();
   services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService.MyService>(); // <- added MyService as implementation
}
```

So after that I was able to use service in my controller class

```
public class BPMController : ControllerBase
{
  private readonly IMyService _myService;

  public MyController(IMyService myService)
  {
    _myService = myService;
  }
}
```

That's fine. However `IMyService` is defined in another class library which I called **MyDomain** and `MyService` is defined in class library which I called **MyService**. Now in order to be able to configure `MyService` as implementation if `IMyService` in my API project I had to add project reference to both **MyDomain** and **MyService** class library. This adds dependency in my API project to **MyService** project which should be avoided by IoC pattern. I did look at various posts here in stackoverflow, but nowhere I found clear answer. So how to set `MyService` as implementation of `IMyService` in my API project **without** referencing **MyService** project? It does not matter which IoC container you use in answer (ninject, unity,...)

Comment: You explicitly register the implementation of the interface in your web API application, so it has to know about both that interface and its implementation - how else can the registration work? The only change to make is to remove `MyDomain` from the API project's references, as .NET Core's transitive dependency resolution means it will implicitly reference that project via `MyService`. I suggest you do further reading around what IoC and dependency inversion actually means, as you seem to lack understanding of it.

Comment: My question is how to avoid to have burden dependency in my **WebAPI** project to **MyService** project. Concerning MyDomain it is ok to have that dependency in my **WebApi** project as it contains only models and interfaces. Your answer is not really helpfull.

Comment: No, you simply don't understand how dependencies work.

Comment: Even if the `Services` are all `internal`, they can be created through reflection and, as pointed out by @IanKemp, this is transitive. Given that, just put the registration code in the `MyDomain` assembly and mark the `MyService` assembly with `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyDomain")]` so that my `MyDomain` can handle things. You have to add one of those to your unit test assembly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after more research, I come to solution which is fine. Back to whiteboard:

[image]

In this situation although, I'm using DI, I can instantiate my service with

```
Service myService = new Service();
```

which I ultimately wanted to disable (so that no programmer can make that mistake).
This could be done by adding another assembly which would contain references to service projects. This assembly (and only this, not services), will be referenced from API project, and role of this assembly is to do dependency injection instead that API project is doing it. Something like this:

[image]

What is benefit of this approach? Well, now programmers can't do:

```
Service myService = new Service(); //we missing Service class
```

and are forced to instantiate services properly (using DI). That was what I wanted :)

Comment: It doesn't even prevent accidental instantiation if the service is constructed in `ServiceModules`. You could apply `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("assemblyname")]` but you could also just do that now without adding an intermediary

Comment: Your problem is with the first diagram: your API layer does not need to explicitly depend on your Domain layer because it implicitly does so via its dependency on the Service layer. As for your solution to the "problem" of developers manually instantiating objects, instead of obtaining them via DI: that is solved by code reviews, not introducing an unnecessarily convoluted and interdependent project structure. If your devs are taking shortcuts like this, they will take other shortcuts. **You are trying to fix a dev culture issue with code**, which almost never works.